# C++ issue : Cannot allocate an object of abstract type, but why?

Tags: c++, class, object, polymorphism, abstract

This is some classes of my C++ program.

ElementTerrain.h:

```
#ifndef ELEMENTTERRAIN_H_
#define ELEMENTTERRAIN_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ElementTerrain {
public:
    virtual ~ElementTerrain(){}
    virtual string getElement() const = 0;
    virtual string getType() const = 0;
    virtual int getStock() const = 0;
};

#endif /* ELEMENTTERRAIN_H_ */
```

Mine.h:

```
#ifndef MINE_H_
#define MINE_H_

#include "ElementTerrain.h"

using namespace std;

class Mine : public ElementTerrain{
public:
    Mine();
    Mine(bool, bool, int);
    Mine(const Mine &);
    virtual ~Mine();

    string getElement(){
            return "Mine";
        }

    string getType(){
        if(this->ur == true){
            return "UR";}
        if(this->plu == true){
            return "PLU";}
        return "None";
    }

    int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    void setStock(int stock) {
        this->stock = stock;
    }

    bool isUr() {
        return ur;
    }

    bool isPlu() {
        return plu;
    }

private :
    bool ur;
    bool plu;
    int stock;
};

#endif /* MINE_H_ */
```

Mine.cpp:

```
#include "Mine.h"

using namespace std;

Mine::Mine() {
    this->ur = false;
    this->plu = false;
    this->stock = 0;
}

Mine::Mine(bool ur, bool plu, int stock){
    this->ur=ur;
    this->plu=plu;
    this->stock = stock;
}

Mine::Mine(const Mine &m){
    this->ur=m.ur;
    this->plu=m.plu;
    this->stock = m.stock;
}

Mine::~Mine() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

And this is the file where I'm having errors:

```
#include "ElementRobot.h"
#include "Mine.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool ElementRobot::RecolteMine(Terrain& t, ElementRobot& r) {
    if(t.plateau[x][y]->getElem() != NULL){
            if(t.plateau[x][y]->getElem()->getElement() == "Mine"){
                Mine *m = new Mine();
                if(m.getType() == r.getType() && m.getStock()>0 && r.stock<r.cap){
                    m.setStock(m.getStock()-1);
                    t.plateau[x][y]->setElem((Mine) t.plateau[x][y]->getElem());
                    return true;
                }

                if(m.getType() == r.getType() && m.getStock()==0){
                    cout << "Les stocks de cette mine sont épuisés.\n" << endl;
                }

                if(r.stock==r.cap){
                    cout << "Votre robot ne peut pas porter plus de minerai.\n" << endl;
                }

                if(m.getType() != r.getType()){
                    cout << "Ce robot n'est pas adapté à cette mine.\n" << endl;
                }
            }}
            return false;
}
```

I want to create an object of type `Mine` with the copy constructor (here I tried just with the default constructor) but it say that I cannot allocate an object of abstract type `Mine`, even though in my class `Mine` there is no pure virtual method. I'm beginner with C++ and I don't understand my mistake. I couldn't find anything on the Internet either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The signatures of the `Mine`'s member functions do not match those of the base class (missing `const` qualifiers). Therefore, you have not **overridden**, but **overloaded** them and `Mine` continues to be abstract and not instantiable.

It's practically like having this:

```
class Mine {
public:
    // this has to be implemented by deriving classes
    virtual string getElement() const = 0;

    // this is a separate overload
    string getElement() { ... };
};
```

**Solution:** Fix the signatures:

```
string getElement() const { ... }
//                  ^^^^^
```

and so on...

C++11's [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword would help you greatly - it would point out that there's no non-const qualified virtual member function named `getElement` to override.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very usefull, I didn't considerate the difference between overriden and overloaded. I will be more carefull now.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `const` in function declarations.

Look here:

```
class ElementTerrain {
public:
    virtual ~ElementTerrain(){}
    virtual string getElement() const = 0;   //  <- notice 'const'
    virtual string getType() const = 0;   //  <- notice 'const'
    virtual int getStock() const = 0;   //  <- notice 'const'
};
```

So add `const` keyword to `getElement`,`getType` and `getStock` functions.

```
class Mine : public ElementTerrain{
public:
    Mine();
    Mine(bool, bool, int);
    Mine(const Mine &);
    virtual ~Mine();

    string getElement() const{    // notice 'const' is added here..
            return "Mine";
        }

    string getType() const{   // notice 'const' is added here..
        if(this->ur == true){
            return "UR";}
        if(this->plu == true){
            return "PLU";}
        return "None";
    }

    int getStock() const{   // notice 'const' is added here..
        return stock;
    }

    void setStock(int stock) {
        this->stock = stock;
    }

    bool isUr() {
        return ur;
    }

    bool isPlu() {
        return plu;
    }

private :
    bool ur;
    bool plu;
    int stock;

};
```

Also if you want to get rid if this error forever I advice you to add [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) C++11 keyword after function declaration if you want to override functions like this:

```
int getStock() const override{
    return stock;
}
```

In this case your C++ compiler will check if such a virtual function exists in any superclass and will raise a compilation error if it doesn't exist.